# getParameter in JSP sets null to href

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following situation, there's my index.jsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lab2</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Period: <input type="number" name="period" size="50">
    <br>
    Faculty: <input type="text" name="faculty" size="50">
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calculatePaymentForSeveralSemesters?value=<%=request.getParameter("period")%>&faculty=<%=request.getParameter("faculty")%>">Calculate
        payment for several semesters</a>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showTwoSmallestFaculties">Show two smallest faculties</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I want to create the link with dynamical values which I get from inputs. But my result link is `http://localhost:8080/Lab2_war_exploded/calculatePaymentForSeveralSemesters?value=null&faculty=null` and I cannot understand why values from inputs are not added to this href. Can you help me to solve this problem? I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first `getParameter` call receives `period` as parameter, but in your URL you pass a `value` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the page is submitted, you won't get the value of `period` and `faculty` available in the request object.

For the purpose of demo, I have added a `form` with `submit` button. Enter some values for `period` and `faculty` and hit the `submit` button. Now check the link and you will find it to be populated with the desired values e.g. when you hit the `submit` button after entering `10` in the `period` and `test` in the `semester` field, you find the value of link as `http://localhost:8080/TestDynamicProject/calculatePaymentForSeveralSemesters?value=10&faculty=test`.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lab2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <form>
        Period: <input type="number" name="period" size="50"> <br>
        Faculty: <input type="text" name="faculty" size="50"> <br>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calculatePaymentForSeveralSemesters?value=<%=request.getParameter("period")%>&faculty=<%=request.getParameter("faculty")%>">Calculate payment for several semesters</a> 
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showTwoSmallestFaculties">Show two smallest faculties</a> 
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. And is it possible to navigate to another page form jsp with passing parameters by `<input type="submit">`, without creating the link to another page?

Comment: `Is it possible to navigate to another page form jsp with passing parameters by <input type="submit">, without creating the link to another page?` - Yes. Post a new question with the exact requirement.